# What is the git CLI equivalent of `echo 'ref: refs/heads/master' > .git/HEAD`

Tags: git

In other words, is there a safe way to just move `HEAD` without doing anything else?

Comment: You mean `git checkout master`?

Comment: @kabanus no, that's not just a checkout because that let the index and working directory untouched. There is no **one** command line to do that. It depends the initial state.  What do you want to achieve with such actions? what is your initial state? Is there changes uncommited?

Comment: @Philippe you are correct, git checkout updates the working tree which is not what I want. The situation is that the working tree and the index are different trees both derived from master. All I want to do is to tell the CLI to consider master the current branch so that e.g. when I run `git commit` master becomes the new commit's parent.

Comment: So a kind of reverse `git reset`, resetting a different branch to the current HEAD? Something like committing on the current branch, saving it on a temporary branch, resetting the original to HEAD~1, and cherry picking the last commit, finally removing the temporary branch?

Comment: @kabanus The situation you describe is very specific and it's close to the usual scenario where I push a WIP commit to a different branch and then try to restore the repository's state including uncommitted changes (`git reset --soft master` followed by the command I'm looking for). But this question is just about the simple operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref